# Delegate for AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and AVCaptureAudioDataOutput

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I try to get `CMSampleBufferRef` from both `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput`.

**AVCamRecorder.h**

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface AVCamRecorder : NSObject {
}
    @property (nonatomic,retain) AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *videoDataOutput;
    @property (nonatomic,retain) AVCaptureAudioDataOutput *audioDataOutput;

@end
```

**AVCamRecorder.m**

```
#import "AVCamRecorder.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface AVCamRecorder (VideoDataOutputDelegate) <AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate>
@end
@interface AVCamRecorder (AudioDataOutputDelegate) <AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate>
@end


-(id)initWithSession:(AVCaptureSession *)aSession
{

    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {

        //AudioDataoutput
        AVCaptureAudioDataOutput *aAudioDataOutput =  [[AVCaptureAudioDataOutput alloc] init];

        //VideoDataoutput
        AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *aMovieDataOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];


        if ([aSession canAddOutput:aAudioDataOutput]) {
            [aSession addOutput:aAudioDataOutput];
        }        
        if ([aSession canAddOutput:aMovieDataOutput]) {
        [aSession addOutput:aMovieDataOutput];
        }

        [aAudioDataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
        [aMovieDataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

        [self setAudioDataOutput:aAudioDataOutput];
        [self setVideoDataOutput:aMovieDataOutput];

        [self setSession:aSession];

    }
    return self;
}

@implementation AVCamRecorder (VideoDataOutputDelegate)
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"VideoDataOutputDelegate = %@", captureOutput);
}    
@end

@implementation AVCamRecorder (AudioDataOutputDelegate)
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"AudioDataOutputDelegate = %@", captureOutput);
}
@end
```

Strangely, I got video data in the "`@implementation AVCamRecorder (AudioDataOutputDelegate)`"

```
AudioDataOutputDelegate = <AVCaptureVideoDataOutput: 0x208a7df0>
```

I switched the order of "`@implementation AVCamRecorder (VideoDataOutputDelegate)`" and "`@implementation AVCamRecorder (VideoDataOutputDelegate)`", and I got

```
VideoDataOutputDelegate = <AVCaptureVideoDataOutput: 0x208a7df0>
```

It seems that I cannot setup 2 "`captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:`". Otherwise, the data comes into either one.

Or, did I make mistake setting up "`@implementation AVCamRecorder (VideoDataOutputDelegate)`" and "`@implementation AVCamRecorder (AudioDataOutputDelegate)`"?

I think I do not need to separate callback, but I am just wondering what is wrong.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined 2 categories on the same class

```
AVCamRecorder (VideoDataOutputDelegate)
AVCamRecorder (AudioDataOutputDelegate)
```

declaring the same method

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection;
```

This results in ***undefined behavior***. See [Avoid Category Method Name Clashes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW4) in the "Programming with Objective-C" guide:

> If the name of a method declared in a category is the same as a method
>   in the original class, or a method in another category on the same
>   class (or even a superclass), the behavior is undefined as to which
>   method implementation is used at runtime.
>   ...

So your setup cannot work. You could instead

- Define two separate *classes*, one as audio and one as video delegate,
- define a single class category acting as audio + video delegate (and check in the callback method for which function it is called),
- just use `AVCamRecorder` itself as audio + video delegate.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It makes to me. Actually, I didn't understand category. I really appreciate.